# Partially disable annotatorjs

Tags: annotatorjs

I am using http://annotatorjs.org/ in my project,
I need to partially disable it

```
<div>
 Some text
   <div>
     Some more Text // Disable annotator in this one.
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Annotator plugin looks for a `<p>` or `<div>` tag to put in an ID with of *content* by default in their documentation.

Since the stable version is used with jQuery, one can change the required tags to have a different **ID** or **class** of choice.

Read about it here - [Setting Up Annotator](http://docs.annotatorjs.org/en/v1.2.x/getting-started.html#setting-up-annotator).